# display last inserted id in view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want display value of last inserted id in view file..
my model

**Model_auto**

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->insert('person',$data);
$id=$this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->query("update person set status='verified' where person_id='$id'");
$this->db->trans_complete();
return $id;
```

**controller**

```
     $this->model_auto->add_user();
     echo '<script>alert("Data Registered Successfully");</script>';
     $this->load->view('fee_view');
```

i dont know how to access that id in controller and then pass to view and display there. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `$this->db->insert_id();` to get the last id:

```
$this->model_auto->add_user();
$data['last_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
$this->load->view('fee_view', $data);
```

and in your view:

```
echo $last_id;
```

Comment: it displays blank when i echo $last_id

Comment: try to var_dump the result of insert_id()

Comment: If none of the answers helped you please edit your own qeustion and write the solution, maybe it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

In your controller do this:

```
$data['id'] = $this->model_auto->add_user();
echo '<script>alert("Data Registered Successfully");</script>';
$this->load->view('fee_view', $data);
```

Now in your view file wherever you want to display the id just do `echo $id;`

Comment: i tried but it's not working...it displays nothing in view when echo $id

Comment: i tried but it's not working...it displays nothing in view when echo $id

Comment: in your model `$data` is coming from where?

Comment: print `id` in your model and controller and see if its printing

Comment: it's not printing $id value

Comment: in model...this is my code...$this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('person',$data);
    $id=$this->db->insert_id();
  
    $this->db->query("update person set status='verified' where   person_id='$id'");
  
  //$this->db->query("insert into child (child_person_id,gender) values ($id,$gender)");
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    var_dump($id);
    echo $id;
    return $id;

Comment: $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('person',$data);
    $id=$this->db->insert_id();
  
  $this->db->query("update person set status='verified' where person_id='$id'");
  
  //$this->db->query("insert into child (child_person_id,gender) values ($id,$gender)");
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    var_dump($id);
    echo $id;
    return $id;

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
 function add_user($data)
 {
  $this->db->trans_start();
  $this->db->insert('person',$data);
  $id=$this->db->insert_id();

  $this->db->query("update person set status='verified' where person_id='$id'");

  //$this->db->query("insert into child (child_person_id,gender) values ($id,$gender)");
  $this->db->trans_complete();
  return $id;
}
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('model_auto','model_auto',TRUE);
$data['id'] = $this->model_auto->add_user($yourData);
$this->load->view('fee_view', $data);
```

and View:

```
echo $id;
```